# IIS is not picking up my updated code

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net website which was working on iis perfectly.I just added else cases to my if just to handle null exception and its working fing when i debug from visual studio but when i deploy it to local iis it throws exception.

My code is

```
if (txtflat.Text != "")
               { comm.Flat_Commission = Convert.ToDouble(txtflat.Text); }
                else { comm.Flat_Commission = Convert.ToDouble(0.0); }
```

and The error is i see is

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +14777139SalesCommissionUtility.User.viewCommission.btnAddCommission_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1811System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11764877System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1665
```

Comment: Not just modified the title. Always edit your question to reflect what has been discussed, and the latest question status.

Answer (score 0):

Check it. Text can be null or "". `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("text")` method will check both null or "".

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtflat.Text))
   { 
       comm.Flat_Commission = Convert.ToDouble(txtflat.Text); 
   }
else 
   { 
       comm.Flat_Commission = Convert.ToDouble(0.0); 
   }
```

Comment: iis is not picking up my updated code even i edit some tag its not showing me that tagI have aslo tried your code

Comment: why i am facing this issue? Even my html heading doesnot update

Comment: You should not get any error with my code. Because if textbox null or "" then it will go else. Refresh your iis site or restart iis.

Comment: i have restarted my iis and website and rebooted iis but no progress

Comment: May be your files did not replace. Try to delete all and paste new files.

Comment: Same directory i am using fro visual studio and same for iis website.For visual studio it shows changes but not iis

Comment: @Pro Grammer Got it. Please close your vs and refresh your files from iis.

Comment: how to refresh from iis??

Comment: @Pro Grammer Go to iis then right click on your site then you will see refresh option.

Comment: Okay now you do one thing. Publish your project or copy your project and paste in different location then make new test site in iis with new location folder project then test. @Pro Grammer

Comment: @Pro Grammer any luck?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a safer approach:
use

> Double.TryParse

to avoid any possible mistake / exceptions:

```
double val;
if (Double.TryParse(txtflat.Text, out val)){
   comm.Flat_Commission = val;
}
else{
   //input text is not well formatted. Handle this situation programmatically
}
```

Generally speaking, handling doubles require a little bit of care as in different cultures there are different separators for the decimal part (eg. quote instead of point).

Anyway, the error is quite clear in the exception message you get: input string (txtflat.Text) can't be parsed to double, as it's format is incorrect.

Comment: I see but iis is not picking up my updated code even i edit some tag its not showing me that tag

Comment: That's another question: you could force to reload your AppDomain by recycling related Application Pool in IIS Manager. By default settings, changing a DLL file in bin folder or changing your web.config will reload AppDomain automatically. If you make any change in a non server-side file (eg. html, css, js), a web page refresh (ctrl+f5) is enough to see your changes online. IMHO you're not browsing your actual Visual Studio project, but a published version somewhere else. Please add more details of your actual configuration to get proper help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was IIS was not picking my checks because Visuai Studio was not updating my files.The issue was with my user account of windows.I logged in from administrative account made all changes and then updated and it started working.I hope this will help anyone facing same problem.